# Showing a given map is diagonalizable without calculating the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a linear map with matrix in the canonical bases is given by

$$A=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2&0&1\\ 0&2&-1
\\ 1&-1&1\end {array} \right]$$

1) Do we have $\mathbb R^3=ker(f)\oplus im(f)$?

2) Is $A$ diagonalizable? justify your answer.

**My answer**

1) We only need to check that $ker(f)\cap im(f)=\{0\}$. Let $v=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$. we have that $v\in ker(f)$ implies $y=-x$ and $z=-2x$. Moreover, $v\in im(f)$ implies $2z-x+y=0$. Hence $v$ is in the intersection only if $v=0$. Is there any other way to show this.

2)From 1) we have that $\mathbb R^3=ker(f)\oplus im(f)=E_0\oplus im(f)$
but i don't see how to get from here to justify the diagonalizability of $A$. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is a real symmetric Matrix. As such a factorization $A=Q\cdot D \cdot Q^T$ exists where Q is a orthogonal Matrix ($Q^T=Q^{-1}$) and $D$ is diagonal. So every real symmetric Matrix is diagonalizable. You may look up a proof here: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_sed.html (I did not check it).

Comment: Actually the homework seems to suggest using question 1. Otherwise yes every symmetric matrix is diagonalisable. Thank you Stephan!